# Doubly Linkedlist in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I wrote the below code just for fun to create doubly LinkedList but it leads to circular referencing. How do i stop the circular referencing?

```
const node = function (value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
  this.prev = null;
}


let head = new node(null);
let current = head;


const newnode = new node('1');
newnode.prev = current;
current.next = newnode;
current = current.next;
```

In js, it(above code) leads to circular nesting as its an object. I am worried about memory leak issues coz of this. Any better way to implement Doubly.

Comment: Whats so bad about circular referencing?! If one node needs to know the next node, which needs to know the previous node, thats automatically a circular reference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Maybe there's a better alternative We can suggest. It would only be a problem if you try to serialize the list.

Comment: In js, it(above code) leads to circular nesting as its an object. I am worried about memory leak issues

Comment: i was just doing it for knowledge/fun  nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** You can not.

In a doubly linked list, an element holds the reference to the next and the previous element.

If from the element `A` you have a reference to the next element `B`, and from the element `B` you have a reference to the previous element `A`, that by definition is a circular reference.

Maybe what you're looking for is the [Singly linked list](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) structure?

Comment: i know whats singly linked list. In js, it(doubly) leads to circular nesting as its an object. I am worried about memory issues coz of this

Comment: Only one instance will be actually saved, there is no memory impact. It only stores the reference in "memory" to the next/previous object.